# How do I mitigate a scenario where a user goes to pay, but the price is changed mid-request?

Tags: concurrency, client-server, http-request, backend, latency

This is kind of similar to the [Two Generals' Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem), but not quite. I think there is a name for it, but I just can't remember it right now.

I am working on my website's payment flow.

### Scenario

1. Alice wants to pay Bob for a service. Bob has quoted her US$10.
2. Alice clicks pay.
3. Whilst Alice's request is flying through the ether, Bob edits his quote. He now wants US$20.
4. Bob's request finishes before Alice's has reached the server.
5. Alice's request reaches the server and her payment is authorized for US$20 instead of US$10.
6. Alice is unhappy.

Whilst the chances of this are very low in practice, it is a possible scenario. Sometimes requests can hang due to network issues, etc...

### Possible Mitigations

I don't think this problem is solvable. But we can do things to mitigate it.

This is not exactly an idempotency issue, so I don't think the answer is "idempotency token".

#### Option 1

Let's define:

- `t_0` as the time Alice click pay.
- `t_edit` as the time Bob's edit request succeeds
- `t_1` as the time Alice's request reaches the server

Since we cannot know `t_0` unless we send it as part of the request data, *and* because we cannot trust what the client sends, we will ignore `t_0`.

At the time Alice's request arrives in the server, we check:

`if t_1 - t_edit < 1 minute: return "409 Conflict"` (or some other code)

Would this approach work? `1 minute` is an arbitrary choice, and it doesn't solve the problem entirely. If Alice's request takes 1 minute or more to reach the server, the issue persists.

**This must be an extremely common problem to deal with, right?**

Comment: This is called a "mid-air collision". And yes, it is a common problem with any distributed system.

Comment: The wrong thing to do here is to jump to conclusions - ask the business how the price-setting process works, and what's their policy on this. For example, if a price has been published, and then it changes mid-request, the business may *not care at all* - it could be that they are perfectly fine with the price being the one that was listed when the request was made. That is, there may be no concept of "THE price" in the domain, but a concept of "price at a given date". Understand what they actually want and design a solution around that.

Comment: This is what it means to understand the domain - don't solve for fictional problems (and potentially introduce unintended real ones). Check how the domain actually operates instead.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I am the sole developer and product/business owner for this. To address your point, I am building a platform that has to cater to both Alice and Bob equally as both will be customers of the business and neither will be happy to pay/receive more/less than what they agreed with each other - hence the consistency requirement.

Comment: Alice's request should include either the amount she intends to pay, a unique id of the (immutable) quote she intends to pay, or both. Then it would not be processed if the price is different or the quote has been rescinded and a different quote provided.

Comment: @turnip - in that case you can find people that are representative of your target customers (the business that will use your software/platform), and ask them what they are currently using, how they are doing it, and what issues they have with their current software or practices; then you can solve *those* problems in your software. And you can specifically ask them about this issue as well. Maybe, after some deliberation, it turns out they don't like the idea that their customers can make these changes at any moment.

Comment: @turnip - I read some of your comments to the answers below: think of the quote as of a contract proposal between Alice & Bob; if either of them changes anything, it's a *new* contract; Bob must provide another quote, before Alice can accept/pay. If that makes sense, then the issue that remains is controlling the dynamics (cadence) of the interaction. How often can changes be made? Is the agreement automatically invalidated on any change, or does the user have to explicitly "commit" a group of changes in an additional step before they take effect., etc

Comment: Turnip: You cater to Bob, because Bob pays _your_ Bill, not Alice. But you don’t do what you think makes Bob happy - you do what he asks you to do. If Alice sees the quote and doesn’t get the item for that price, Bob should know that she will be pissed off and never goes near that store. And Bob should know that if you actually charged more than advertised, there may be legal action. The way to prevent this is to remove the item from the store for some time, then return it with a different price. Bob doesn’t want his customers to see price increases.

Comment: Why not make it a two step process? Bob gives quote. Alice accepts quote. Bob is notified of acceptance and price is locked. Alice is free to pay the agreed price. This would also allow to separate the quote phase from the paying phase, more easily implementing things like pay after the job, or pay half before half after.

Comment: @bracco23 I have certainly thought about that. But again, that isn't the core problem I was trying to solve. A mid-flight collision can still occur in this scenario. I think a few people across the comments and answers are missing that point. Regarding your suggestion, I am hesitant to implement it because it prolongs the entire process a bit and that risks losing a customer. I think there are more efficient solutions that achieve the same security for both sides (and consistency).

Comment: @turnip I agree in general mid-flight collisions are still a problem, my suggetion was to just take a different approach in general to make the abstracted process closer to what happens in real life. True, process would be longer, but it would work much more like it works now without your tool, so it would be easier for people to adapt to it.

Comment: @turnip Most shops and games handle two cases differently: **Case 1:** There is a Seller and a Buyer - the Seller can freely set price and conditions on an offer and the Seller can just accept/reject. Usually Bob would have a standard list of offerings with stable prices, so there is seldom a case he would not accept a sale for a price he was OK with before. -- **Case 2:** Alice can request certain details and Bob gives a quote for the request. Exact details of the contract are negotiable from both sides. You could clarify in the question which case you are handling.

Comment: This happened to me in a parking garage once. After displaying the price I had to pay I inserted my card and it eventually stated the transaction was cancelled. Then the price went up. I was pretty pissed.

Comment: And this is why you use Transactions. Either the run finishes on the same data or the run doesn't finish, but there is no race condition.

Comment: However you try to solve the problem, you can very easily reduce the likelihood that it happens: Let Bob edit prices any time he wants, but apply the changes at 3am in the morning, when (almost) nobody is shopping.

Comment: Is it a typical concurrency problem? And is the solution is Optimistic/Pessimistic Concurrency?

Comment: This is more a legal/contract thing as a technical. Typically a quote has a specific time frame in which it is legally binding. You can implement it exactly like that.

Comment: It's always 3 AM *somewhere*. By the very same logic, it is also always 11 PM *somewhere*. Also, even if you *assume* a single TZ, people (and their machine agents) still do transactions at strange times. In my experience, this doesn't reduce the probability in a useful way.

Comment: @Ahmad this is not a typical concurrency problem. Because the transaction boundaries are "Alice sees a price" and "Booking confirmed" - if Alice remembers the price and takes a coffee break and only clicks pay afterwards, this "transaction" could span minutes to hours. And if you want to be customer friendly, just displaying the new price is probably not enough - you have to make sure to inform Alice that the price has changed and make sure she is ok with the new price.

Comment: I'll add to what @Filip wrote.  This is a bit of an XY question about business rules [no offense to the O.P.] .  I don't know about other jurisdictions, but where I live quotes and purchase orders are binding.  If Bob sends Alice a quote, and Alice issues a purchase order, Bob has to deliver on that purchase order per terms in the quote.  Bob can not change that quote for Alice.

Comment: Naturally, a quote is somewhat of a liability for Bob.  [Did anyone tell Bob that doing business and working with customers is easy?]  To mitigate that somewhat, each quote should have an expiration date, which could be as long as a month, or as short as thirty seconds.

Comment: If it isn't binding, then it isn't called "quote", perhaps it could be called "estimate".  How often is the binding nature of quotes legally enforced?  Rarely.  However, designing a system with support for non-binding quotes feels... odd.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

> - Alice wants to pay Bob for a service. Bob has quoted her $10.

Give this quote a unique token.

> - Alice clicks pay.

When this response is send to the server, it must go with the token of what is being paid. *This also allows you to discard duplicate payments.*

> - Whilst Alice's request is flying through the ether, Bob edits his quote. He now wants $20.
> - Bob's request finishes before Alice's has reached the server.

That has a new different token※. The server must invalidate the old one.

> - Alice's request reaches the server and her payment is authorized for $20 instead of $10.

No, it isn't. Alice token does not match.

※: The server must send Alice the new quote, with the new token. And alice must click pay again.

---

For user experience, you can also add a timeout. That prevents the token to be used right away. This timeout can either be only client side or networked. The purpose is to give some time to the user to notice the change.

> This must be an extremely common problem to deal with, no?

Many online video games that allow players to trade face this problem. A simple 5 seconds timeout can save support a lot of headaches.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer because it addresses the core of the issue. Whilst the other answers provide useful suggestions, they don't fully tackle the problem. Your solution ensures consistency AND still leaves room for flexibility; Bob can still edit his quote as many times as he wants. I will implement @Hans-Martin's suggestion of invalidating quotes when Alice changes her requirements too.

Comment: @turnip oh, yes. In fact, Games usually have players trading objects and money both ways in a single exchange.

Comment: One way how some card payment protocols do it is by having the token include (or be) a cryptographically secure hash or signature of the key fields of the transaction, obviously including the amount, so that at both sides (and any intermediary systems) it is possible to check if it matches, and nobody can maliciously alter the quote corresponding to the token without invalidating it.

Comment: Token is a good idea if you want Alice to be able to purchase at the old price for a certain period even if Bob changes the price.  If that's not a requirement, Alice can just send the price *she* agreed on.  If it doesn't match the price Bob is currently quoting, you can return a failure code with the updated price so you can display a message about the price increasing...

Comment: Ah, just read all the comments.  The video game example with a token is good.  Like in WOW when you open a trade window, you each put items/money into the trade.  When you are happy with it, you click 'accept'.  If the other party makes any changes, your 'accept' is no longer valid.  In this example you need a record of exactly what each person thought the agreement was.  That would involve keeping track of updates on the server with some sort of token, or recording the last thing each party agreed to until it matched.

Comment: Give the quote a unique token, or the price by which the quote was generated - so the price against the quote has a unique token than the price set by Bob?

Comment: This makes sense, you shouldn't think of it as Bob changing a property of the quote - a quote should be immutable. Rather by changing the price Bob is withdrawing the original quote and creating a new one. Generally in systems I've seen this, the id is a 2-tuple - the first element is fixed when Bob creates the quote and the second increments each time Bob amends a field. That way you can track change over time but ensure that both parties are manipulating the same object.

Comment: Not just shouldn't you change the quote mid-transaction because it makes Bob look bad to Alice, it's probably (depending on jurisdiction) illegal to do so. I know that here consumer protection law specifically says you cannot do that. Especially you can't just charge someone's bank account or credit card more than the agreed upon amount. You can charge less, but if you do so you're then not allowed to later charge the rest as well.

Comment: I'd call this "I accept your offer" vs "I'll buy at the current price". It's clear the latter can go wrong.

Comment: "That has a new different token. The server must invalidate the old one." Not necessarily. It would be just as valid to process Alice's request, charge the $10, and require Bob to perform the service.

Comment: In the UI this would likely manifest as something like: "Oops, it appears this quote has changed. The new quote is $x"

Comment: Worth noting that this (and other financial transactions) require that your database be ACID compliant and strongly consistent.  To be safe, I would use strict serializability.

Answer (score 58):

A quote should be a write-once record.

Bob isn't allowed to edit it once it has been created and passed to Alice.

You can ensure this at different levels, from simply not offering an edit dialog to sophisticated digital signature algorithms.

Comment: Perhaps some meaning has been lost in my simplified example. The reason Bob can edit his quote is because Alice's requirements can be edited too. If she edits her requirements then Bob might want to edit his quote.

Comment: New requirements, new quote (which likely invalidates the old one.) If Bob offer one Whatsit for 10$, Alice can either accept this quote as it is, or request a new quote for 2 Whatsits.

Comment: @turnip it sounds like you need to separate the "edit requirements" and "pay" steps, so that that both parties know which offer is being accepted

Comment: @turnip If Alice has changed the request, the quote should be invalidated.  Otherwise she could game the system: request a quote for one widget.  Get a quote from Bob.  Then change the request to 10 widgets and hit the "buy now" button before Bob has a chance to update the quote.

Comment: @Caleth yes, it looks like that could be the way to go. Currently "Alice" has more power when it comes to accepting an offer because accepting and payment is one step. If I introduce a separate "accept" step which both parties must carry out, then I can proceed with payment. What Hans is suggesting could work too.

Comment: @SimonB You're right. I think invalidating the quote will be the way to go... less friction in terms of UX for both parties.

Comment: @turnip - who are you making this for? Can you ask them how they handle changing requirements, how much negotiation they want to allow, and how they might want to structure the process? It may turn out that they have a way of doing it that avoids this problem completely.

Comment: @turnip in that case it's a new offer to a new set of requirements, the original quote keeps linked to the original set of requirements. Do NOT allow editing of quotes and requirements/order forms while quotes are being processed. If Alice changes her order, cancel the quote and issue a new one. If Bob notices he made an error in his quote, cancel the quote and issue a new one (if Alice hasn't accepted the existing one yet, in which case Bob has entered a legal contract and will need to renegotiate to fix that error).

Comment: @turnip most games handle this kind of deal with a double-accept. Both parties are symmetric, each one first edits their request and then locks it in (Alice requests 2 green Foobars and Bob requests 10$) After lock-in, each party has to accept the final deal. If Bob did already press "accept" and then Alice edits her request, Bob will go back to editable and has to lock and accept again.

Answer (score 29):

> This must be an extremely common problem to deal with, no?

No, it isn't. I doubt you'll be able to find a payment processor that lets you change the amount after the customer has authorised a particular amount.

You sell to Alice at the price she authorised, because that's what your quote to her was, and what she authorised. You don't check that the money you received matches what you *currently* quote. If you do check, it's that you issued that quote to Alice in the first place.

Comment: The problem is, how do you know that a customer has authorized a particular amount? The customer authorizes it before you know about it, because it takes time for that authorization message to reach you. During that time when the message is in transit, the customer _has_ authorized it, but you can't know that, meaning at all times you can't know if there's an payment authorization message in flight.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson by locking the quote to changes before the customer has sent a message either accepting or rejecting it, or until a timeout is reached (which depending on context and legal system can be anywhere from seconds to weeks).

Comment: Well, Bob isn't going to be too happy if he comes back to change his quote and is told, "no, we won't allow you to change it; it's locked." Even ignoring that, you're saying that as soon as anybody views the quote, it must be locked to changes until they respond that they will (or perhaps won't) buy the item? That could lock it from changes forever if you don't receive a response. If you unlock it after, say, an hour, what happens to the customer who sent the accept message before you unlocked it, but you didn't receive it until after you locked it? You end up with the same problem again.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson No, it just means that if Bob wants to change his quote, what he's really doing is _cancelling_ the old quote, and creating a new one. Alice's bid is no longer valid, because the original quote has been cancelled. She can choose to bid on the new one.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Depending on jurisdiction, Bob has a contractual obligation to Alice if she authorises payment, and *can't* change the quote without Alice's agreement.

Comment: Unless Bob has specifically stated that the quote will continue to be valid for a certain time, Bob has no obligation to maintain his offer indefinitely; he can chance or cancel it at any time before Alice delivers to him notice of acceptance. And even if he has stated that in his quote, it's not a contract because it's missing two criticial parts of contracts: [acceptance and consideration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract#Offer_and_acceptance).

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson probably not indefinitely, but the "here's my offer of <goods / services> for <price>", "here's payment of <price>" is acceptance, and the <goods / services> and payment are each side's consideration. It's entirely analogous to a shop being required to sell at the price it shows on the shelf, even if that was an error, which is the case *in some jurisdictions*

Comment: The situation in the question is not what you described; it's: A: "Here's my offer." A: "I rescind the offer." B: "I accept the offer." At that point, A has no obligation to B since B tried to accept an offer that was no longer available. Nor was there ever any contractual relationship there, since A had no counterparty when we made the offer and A received no consideration for making the offer.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson if someone rescinds an offer once, I'm an unhappy customer. If he rescinds an offer twice, an ex-customer. But this has nothing to do with software engineering, it's just about policies. In business, behaving reliably is purely self-interest, because you're just going out of business if your word can't be trusted.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner You must be pretty upset with almost every shop you ever shop at, then, since they regularly change (when their price goes up) and resciend (when they run out of an item) offers. Not guaranteeing an offer will be available forever, or any length of time at all, is extremely common in the business world.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson But not whilst you have the item in your (physical) basket, or your card in their eftpos

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson actually, in Germany where I live, prices in shops are binding. If the price tag at the shelf says an item costs 4.99€ the shop owner is not allowed to change his mind in the time I take it to the register. Same for gasoline prices which change several times a day. Once I have started pumping the price is fixed. Of course, if I see a price quote on Monday and come back on Thursday to buy the item, I can't expect the price to be unchanged.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson You are confusing different situations. Your argument (shop pricing changes, which happen irregularly and often with advance notice) does not work for the use case of the question at hand (price changing practically at the same time as the purchase). In a real shop, if I pick up an item and a clerk changes the price tag while I'm walking to the cash register, the shop might be legally obligated to honor the price tag that was there when I picked up the item. Not at all the same as coming Monday and returning Tuesday expecting the same price.

Comment: @Aaron I think it's you confusing the situations; putting something in a shopping basket online is not at all the same as putting a physical item in a shopping basket. In the latter case, once you've put an item in your basket, nobody else can put the item in theirs; this serves as a form of "lock."  That may not be desirable, but there's no way around it.

Comment: In the web case you (usually) don't want to mark the item "out of stock" when someone puts it in their basket because they may just leave it there without buying it. (I frequently leave things in my web basket without purchase as an easy way to get back to it a few days later, if it's still available. Amazon regularly tells me, "The price of items in your basket has changed.")

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Putting item in the online basket does nothing to lock price, but when you're starting checkout process price must be locked.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Actually, some online purchasing systems do exactly that: when one person has started a purchase for something, or sometimes even before the final checkout process, it is marked as unavailable even if the transaction has not completed yet. If the transaction is cancelled or a timeout period has expired, then the lock is released. That is something that good online purchasing systems include, and it's not uncommon.

Comment: @Aaron Well, that's certainly one approach, but if you've done any reasonably comprehensive study of market mircostructure, you'll know why it's not a good one. (And maybe you'll even be using it for adverserial attacks aginst the customers of those markets.)

Comment: @user11153 Really? Well Amazon disagrees with you, because they don't lock the price until I agree to pay it, a step or two _after_ I start the checkout. (They also let me wait as long as I want, days even, to complete a checkout I've "started.")

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson But there *is* a separation between "adding to cart" and "authorising payment"

Comment: @Caleth Yes, exactly! In fact, the second might not even happen!

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner No you are wrong - prices in shops (in Germany) are not binding. The price tags on a shelf are not an offer from the shop (no "Willenserklärung") but the shop requests the customer to make an offer themselves at the register which the shop owner can either accept or decline (invitatio ad offerendum). This works the same way with online services and thereby makes it possible for the webserver to not accept a sale contract if the item is out of stock or the price changed.

Answer (score 20):

Just send the amount Alice agreed to pay along with the request. If the price has increased since Alice sent the request, you send a response indicating that the item could not be purchased at or below that price, and the current price is whatever it is. This is pretty much the same situation as when there's only one item available and, at the time the request to buy reaches you, the item has already been sold.

So your message flow would look like:

```
   Bob → Server  Set item price to $10
 Alice → Server  Tell me item price.
Server → Alice   Item price is $10.
   Bob → Server  Set item price to $20.
 Alice → Server  Purchase item for $10.
Server → Alice   Item not available for $10; current price is $20.
```

This is, in fact, exactly how things work in trading systems connected to exchanges. (I wrote one about ten years ago.) You never know what bids and offers are *currently* on the exchange; you know only what was there a few milliseconds ago. And even if what was there is still there now, it may not still be there when your order reaches the exchange.

Comment: Going along with the exchange example, an alternative solution would be to present different order types to the customer.  Let them choose "just give me the current market price, I'll pay whatever it is" vs "I will pay $x or better, and I'm ok if my order isn't executed right away."  (Though make sure to take precautions to prevent the first option from being abused, such as limiting the frequency of price updates from the seller.)

Comment: @0x5453 Yes, those are known as "market" and "limit" orders. I was trading cash-settled options on futures of an index, and market orders were almost never used. (I certainly never used them.) There's no "abuse" in changing your orders frequently; it's quite normal to cancel old orders before they've been filled. The only limit is on how fast you can send your orders to the exchange, which can easily be several dozen per second.

Comment: There could be abuse for a website like this where there are not regulating bodies in place to prevent such.  For example, sellers could repeatedly flash between a reasonable offer and some insane number, hoping that a few users will use market orders without paying attention to the price updates during "checkout".

Comment: @0x5453 only if all of them work together. Because a market order means to buy at the lowest available price.

Comment: @JosefsaysReinstateMonica Which matters for something high volume. But when selling a thing or a service on a website, the negotiation is very local and is surely possible to only have 1 bidder. In this case they control the entire "market"

Comment: This means trusting user data--a very big no-no.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - this answer doesn't require trusting user data. If Alice sends a message for `Purchase item for $0.01` or even `Purchase item for -$10.` the Server will just respond with `Item not available for that price; current price is $x.`

Comment: @Loren Or to put it in another way, it's pefectly fine to trust user data when the user data is, "I am willing to pay up to $10 for one of these, but I will not purchase it if it's more than that."

Comment: @MartinSmith Only if you're willing to reject the transaction because the price changed in the middle.

Comment: @Loren That goes back to the core confusion here. The transaction did not start when the seller posted his offer. The transaction started _when the seller received an acceptance of the offer_. If that acceptance was received after the seller revoked the offer, clearly there can be no transaction.

Comment: A: "Buy $10" Server: "price $10 enter card" B: "price now $20" A:"card xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",  Sever: "Alice, here is product. Bob, here is $10" B: "WTF?"

Comment: @Jasen On most shopping sites you do not contract to purchase until _after_ you've entered your card information. See, e.g., Amazon.com.

Answer (score 8):

Yes this is a common issue, and it is about transactional consistency.

To summarize your issues:

- the quote is binding for the seller.  In general it has a reference and an expiration date/time.
- the buyer may buy under the condition of an accepted quote.  The buyer cannot be forced to accept a price that was not agreed.
- if a buyer finishes the transaction before the expiration of the quote, there is no ambiguity about which price to use. But if you allow the seller to change the quote, either the price should be the one that the buyer accepted when starting the purchase, or the user should give consent to the price of the new quote.
- if the buying transaction is started before the price change, but not finished in time, we are in an ambiguous situation in which the seller could decide not to accept the purchase under the old price; but the buyer is not obliged to buy under the new price. If we are speaking of minutes and seconds, the practice is often to accept the initiated transaction.
- finally, there might be no explicit quote for a buyer, in the scenario of a public price list for a catalogue.
- the main problem in your specific situation, is that you have no certainty about the time at which Alice initiated the request: you only have a time for the completion of the payment.

One solution that works for both, quotes and public price lists, is to give a certainty to the start time of the transaction. So before proceeding to the payment, Alice must confirm her intention to buy. Exactly like with your Amazon basket. If at this moment the price was already changed, Alice could decide to accept and continue, or to cancel the purchase.

Since you now know the purchase initiation date, you can fine-tune your business rules (e.g. accepting a payment within 10 minutes, or more, or less).

From a technical point of view, this approach can be used to implement the [**saga pattern**](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) that fully solves the issue:

- preparatory actions (request a quote, issue a quote, consult a quote) that are all cancellable, until a pivot event;
- all actions happening after the pivot are just optimistically performed as if we’d be sure of a positive outcome;
- but the these actions must stay reversible (status "in progress", with undo possibility) until the last event of the saga is performed (payment completed in your case).

The saga is a more flexible alternative to a distributed [two phase commit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

And if Alice and Bob were on the same system, there wouldn’t be an issue at all thanks to ACID [isolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)).

Answer (score 4):

Bob changed the price at time t. Alice ordered at a time t’ which is close to t. Bob would have had no problem to charge the lower price, had she ordered 10 minutes away from t.

So you record not only the current price, but also the previous price and when it was changed. In Alice’s order you include the price she has seen.

When the order arrives and doesn’t match the current price: If it doesn’t match the previous price either, you fail (some dodgy request). If the price increased, but more than ten minutes ago, you fail. Otherwise, that is the price was lowered or changed in the last ten minutes, you charge the lower of current and previous price.

All this of course if Bob agrees. The “ten minutes” can be made longer. Easy to implement, and it keeps customers happy. If Bob prefers to make customers unhappy, or never return to the shop, you implement something else.

To make the situation less common, let Bob edit the prices at any time, but apply all the changes at 3am in the night when (almost) nobody is ordering.

Answer (score 2):

In an API world, this would be solved by resource versioning. The resource can be versioned internally, for example with a time stamp.

For a standardized mechanism, an [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) can be used.

This allows for semantics such as "the thing we talked about earlier, I'd like to perform an operation on it, if things are still the same"

Answer (score 1):

While [Theraot's solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/404121) of associating each price offer from Bob with a unique token works (and may have some additional benefits like preventing Alice from accidentally paying for the same service twice, assuming that's not something she'd normally ever want to do), for this particular problem there's an even simpler solution:

**Include the price that Alice is willing to pay in her purchase request.**

(Edit: This is essentially the same solution as [suggested by Curt J. Sampson](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/404152) earlier. Somehow I failed to notice their answer before writing mine.  I'll leave this answer here since it includes some additional details, but I encourage you to upvote their answer too if you like this one.)

With that single modification, your example scenario now works out like this (with changes *in italics*):

1. Alice wants to pay Bob for a service. Bob has quoted her US$10.
2. Alice clicks pay, *sending a request to purchase Bob's service for US$10 to the server*.
3. Whilst Alice's request is flying through the ether, Bob edits his quote. He now wants US$20.
4. Bob's request finishes before Alice's has reached the server.
5. Alice's request reaches the server and *is rejected, since the price of US$10 that Alice is offering to pay does not match the US$20 that Bob is now asking*.
6. *Alice receives a message that her purchase failed due to a price mismatch, and she must now choose between repeating the purchase with the new price of US$20 or rejecting the new offer*. Alice is *mildly annoyed at Bob for suddenly switching prices like that*.

---

Note that, since the price of US$10 included in Alice's request in step 2 comes from Alice's browser, which is under her control, she could fairly easily modify the request to try and get a cheaper price.  However, the server-side comparison of the prices in step 5 will also protect you and Bob against any such attacks by Alice: any attempt by Alice to unilaterally lower the price she's paying will just give her the same notice of a price mismatch and force her to retry the purchase, just as if Bob had changed the price.

If you want, you *can* try to distinguish these two scenarios, e.g. by keeping track of recent price changes by Bob on the server and/or by using a [cryptographic token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) passed from the server to Alice and back to verify that Alice's request indeed matches a legitimate prior offer by Bob.  This could be useful if you wanted to know whether Alice was trying to cheat or just a victim of unfortunate circumstances, but *it's not needed to prevent such cheating attempts from working in the first place*.

---

Also note that, if Bob had decided to instead *lower* his price from US$10 to e.g. US$5, you would have several options for handling the mismatch:

- a) reject the request and make Alice repeat it, just like above;
- b) accept Alice's request, but only charge her the new price of US$5, just as if she *had* repeated the request and accepted the new price; or
- c) accept Alice's request and make her pay the original price of US$10, just as if Bob's price change had only happened after Alice's purchase.

In some sense, none of these options is *wrong* — they all (eventually) result in Alice paying a price that both she and Bob had considered acceptable for the service.  That said, going with option (c) seems likely to leave Alice quite unhappy if she realizes what has happened.  Thus, in general, I'd recommend either option (b) or, just possibly, some low-overhead version of (a) where Alice is only shown a quick confirmation dialog where she can click "OK" to accept the new, lowered price.  Anything more than that would be needless overhead for something that Alice almost surely *does* want to do.

Of course, any such confirmation request must also include the new price that Alice now wants to pay, and it must be verified against Bob's offer on the server in order to protect against further price changes by Bob and/or attempts to manipulate the request by Alice.

---

BTW, unless your app includes a real-time feed of price changes from the server to each potential customer's browser, a much more likely version of your scenario is that Bob changes the price *after Alice has loaded the page with the price and the purchase button*, but before she has actually clicked the button.  That's typically a much wider time window than the actual time it takes from Alice's request to reach the server after she clicks the purchase button.  However, it doesn't actually make any practical difference for this scenario whether the price change occurs before or after the button click — in general, neither Alice nor Bob nor the server can even tell anything except that the price has changed *at some point* after Alice loaded the page and before her request reached the server.

(If your app *does* include a real-time price change feed, you'll need to also consider the possibility of Bob changing the price — and this price change reaching Alice's browser — a fraction of a second *before* Alice clicks the button, too late for her brain to react to the change and stop the click.  It would probably be a good idea to disable the purchase button for at least a few seconds after any price change, and to show some very conspicuous notification whenever such a live price change occurs.)

Comment: Sometimes lowering the price of something may create problems for a buyer.  For example, on a site offers free shipping on purchases over $25, and $10 shipping on smaller purchases, cutting the price of something from $26 to $24 may increase by $8 the amount the buyer has to pay unless the buyer adds more items to the purchase.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed, in the presence of such [perverse incentives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_incentive) a price reduction should definitely require confirmation.

Comment: There may not be any intentional perverse incentives on the part of the seller, and indeed the person setting the price might not have any idea of any ways in which lower prices might affect the buyer.  For example, if the goods are being sold in an aggregated-shipping marketplace, the seller may have no monetary interest in the shipping charged by the marketplace, nor any way to know whether the buyer would be near a price threshold.  Personally I think that marketplaces should handle concepts like "Free shipping on orders over $25.00" by making the shipping cost be the lower of...

Comment: ...the "normal cost" or $25.01 minus the order total, so that if normal shipping would be $5.00, then an order of X goods would cost X+$5.00 for X of $20.01 or less, $25.01 exactly for X of $20.01 to $25.01, and X for orders of $25.01 or more.  In such scenarios, it would still be good to ask people if they'd like to order (e.g.) up to $4.73 of free merchandise, but it would not be unreasonable to interpret a lack of a response as confirmation of the original order as given.  Alternatively, in some scenarios it might be reasonable to process the order for the original amount but...

Comment: ...include a "free merchandise" voucher for the price difference, but the feasibility of that would depend upon how the customer's payment was divided among the entities processing the sale.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address two side issues.  How to solve the issue has been addressed by many others.

### Criticality of the issue

You missed steps 7 through 9 in the scenario:

> 1. Alice wants to pay Bob for a service. Bob has quoted her US$10.
> 2. Alice clicks pay.
> 3. Whilst Alice's request is flying through the ether, Bob edits his quote. He now wants US$20.
> 4. Bob's request finishes before Alice's has reached the server.
> 5. Alice's request reaches the server and her payment is authorized for US$20 instead of US$10.
> 6. Alice is unhappy.

7. Alice talks to her credit card company, tells them she agreed to pay US$10, and they agree.
8. Bob gets his US$20.
9. **You** pay the remaining US$10.  Now you are unhappy.

This makes it critical that you deal with it.  Otherwise, some Alice and Bob will collude to take money from you.

### Commonness of the issue

If Alice performs step one on Monday morning, and step two on Friday night, step three could have happened any time in between.  This makes it ridiculously easy to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in most cases there's an intermediate step--shopping carts.  You put the item in the shopping cart rather than buying it.  If there's a price change at the wrong instant you can see it before you press pay.  When you pay you're buying the shopping cart--the items in it already have prices attached.

For a more complete solution you can make making prices read-only.  When Bob raised the price on widgets to $20 he really created a new type of widget that goes for $20, the $10 widget still exists but can not be found unless you know the item ID.  Alice is attempting to purchase the $10 version, the transaction goes through at $10.